# Spring Boot and React: Rendering app.js in index.html of Spring application

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, reactjs

In [this tutorial on using String Data REST with React](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/)
it says to create an HTML file called `index.html` in the Spring Boot project and have a `div` where I can render the React component.

The problem I have is my React app is a completely different project. How do I do this or what else can I do to fix this? Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do two things:

1. You could run them both in separate projects as you have it now and run them on different ports locally, however that means you need to enable cross-origin requests on your server or configure a proxy in the react project. (If you used create-react-app you can just add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` in your `package.json` file where http://localhost:8080 is the url to your backend.).
2. You could move all the files into one project and have your React project run on the embedded Spring server. However this requires some re-configuration of your `webpack.config.js` and some restructuring of files.

I suggest the first option which is easier and also probably how you would like to run your application in the future, with one container for the client-side code and one container for your backend code.